# AngularFire 2 AuthGuard multiple requests

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm trying to make multiple requests to Firebase in my `canActivate()` but TS compiler marks an error: *A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value*.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
      this.auth.take(1).map((authState : FirebaseAuthState) => {
        if(authState) {
        // Ok, so user is authenticated, let's check if it is admin
          return this.db.object(`/users/${authState.uid}`)
          .take(1)
          .map((user) => {
            if(user.isAdmin) {
            // Redirect admin user to /admin-panel
              this.router.navigate(['/admin-panel']);
              return true;
            } else {
             // It is normal user, continue
              return true;
            }
          })
        } else {
          // User not authenticated
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      })
  }
```

So, my problem is that I can not male multiple requests inside `canActivate()`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the `canActivate`, change it to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
      return this.auth.take(1).map((authState : FirebaseAuthState) => {
        if(authState) {
        // Ok, so user is authenticated, let's check if it is admin
          return this.db.object(`/users/${authState.uid}`)
          .take(1)
          .map((user) => {
            if(user.isAdmin) {
            // Redirect admin user to /admin-panel
              this.router.navigate(['/admin-panel']);
              return true;
            } else {
             // It is normal user, continue
              return true;
            }
          })
        } else {
          // User not authenticated
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: This way TS compiler also fails: `Type 'Observable<false | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.
  Type 'Observable<false | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'.
    Property 'then' is missing in type 'Observable<false | Observable<boolean>>'.
`

Comment: What does it say? The same thing?

Comment: Please, check above

Comment: Try changing `: Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>` to `boolean`.

Comment: Also fails :( `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

Answer (score 0):

I have found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589916/angular-2-route-guard-canactivate-based-on-firebase-user-role). So, multiple request can be performed using `mergeMap`.